# Error when calling CreateEnvelope: Invalid Username For Recipient

Tags: c#, asp.net, docusignapi

I am using the updated DocuSign API with my .NET application and for the Authentication, I'm using the Authentication Code Grant workflow using 'signature%20extended' as the Code. I can successfully authenticate and get back an access token for the user I'm authenticating with.

I then get the Account details without any issue

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
var docuSignUserInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(accessToken).Accounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

I then proceed with creating my Signer and Document Model

```
Document document = new Document
            { DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ReadContent(docName)),
              Name = "Lorem Ipsum", FileExtension = "pdf", DocumentId = "1"
            };
Document[] documents = new Document[] { document };

// Create the signer recipient object 
            Signer signer = new Signer
            { Email = "test@example.com", FirstName = "Jane", LastName="Doe" ClientUserId = "1000",
              RecipientId = "1", RoutingOrder = "1"
            };
Signer[] signers = new Signer[] { signer };
Recipients recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers) };

EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
            { EmailSubject = "Please sign the document",
              Documents = new List<Document>( documents ),
              Recipients = recipients,
              Status = "sent"
            };

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);

//This is the API call that throws the error below
EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);


Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
  "errorCode": "INVALID_USERNAME_FOR_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The user name for the recipient is invalid. Envelope definition is missing a UserName for recipientId: 1"
}
```

From my understanding, I shouldn't need to specify any Username/Passwords as I'm using the Access Token for Authentication. Also, I don't understand why a recipient would require a UserName?

Comment: What are you setting as your `signerName` value? Recipients must have a name and email to be valid.

Comment: I have updated my above code to show the values. I was using FirstName and LastName Properties of Signer Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to provide the `Name` property for the `Signer` model. Please try that.

I agree that the `FirstName` and `LastName` sound like they are all that is needed, but those attributes may not be fully implemented yet (or a bug).

Please advise if this solved your problem. Thank you.

**Added**

The `FirstName` and `LastName` attributes are optional. DocuSign internal bug report DEVDOCS-1079 has been filed to have the documentation for those fields improved.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to have worked. Also, the error message is not very intuitive. Maybe this can be revised in the next release of the API version. Thanks!